# How to find which HD controller module a running Linux system is using?

Tags: linux, hp, kernel, hp-proliant

I have a problem with an HP ProLiant Microserver that won't boot with a Slackware 12 system using Linux 2.6.21.5

If I boot a recent version of System Rescue CD, the disk is recognized.

So my question is: how can I find which module is the System Rescue CD kernel using to access the hard disk?

**Edit:**

When trying to boot with Slackware, I get the dreadful message

`Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)`

The filesystem module (`ext3`) is loaded, so it can only be a controller driver issue, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2.6.21, the module for HP SmartArrays is 'cciss'. In more recent kernel versions they've been moving things over to a newer 'hpsa' driver. To find out what modules are driving which hardware, the '

`lspci -k`

command will display which modules are associated with which devices.

```
03:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array P410i
Kernel driver in use: cciss
```

Comment: Hi, this might solve the non-booting server but it's not the answer to the original question. I know that I mixed 2 questions in 1 and it's a bit messy. Should I ask another question for the non-booting server?

Comment: Hi, the driver was not `cciss` but `ahci`, as the ProLiant MicroServer does not have the HP Smart Array Controller. Thanks however for the help!

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I found that the kernel module used by a given subsystem is obtained by `lspci -k`.

In this way I found that the module required by the controller is `ahci`, and I'm going to try and see if this works with my kernel.

Comment: It worked, the server booted flawlessly once I compiled statically `ahci` and set to AHCI the disk setting in the BIOS.